# INSERT em lote c#

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber se é possível e como realizar um INSERT no banco de dados de 10 valores iguais e somando mais 1 em um campo..

ex:
tenho um sistema de patrimônio e preciso cadastrar 10 items iguais.
ao marcar uma checkbox e adicionar a quantidade de items em uma textbox ele adicionar os 10 items ao banco de dados...

preciso que ao gravar seja acrescente +1 ao numero da plaqueta que é vai ser um numero aleatório digitado..

ex:

```
txtPlaqueta.Text = "123"
CheckBox = true;
txtValorRepetir = "10"
```

então ficaria no bd assim

```
123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132
```

se eu mudar o numero da plaqueta para "50" ficaria no bd

```
50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59

private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(//string de conexao);

        txtValor.Text = (int.Parse(txtValor.Text) + 1).ToString();

        string inserir = @"INSERT INTO DadosNome (Nome, Valor, Teste, Deletar) Values ('"+txtNome.Text+"', '"+txtValor.Text+"', '"+txtTeste.Text+"', '"+txtDeletar.Text+ "'),('" + txtNome.Text + "', '" + txtValor.Text + "', '" + txtTeste.Text + "', '" + txtDeletar.Text + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(inserir, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Supondo que a coluna valor tem valor "22" ao fazer o insert ficaria (22,23,24,25) quatro registros no bd.

Comment: basta fazer um loop... mas coloque o codigo que você utiliza pra fazer um insert

Comment: Poderia mostrar algum código, para eu ter noção deste loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há vários problemas no seu código, mas vou focar no loop, e ainda que com uma prática não recomendada (concatenar a string da query) vou mostrar um exemplo de como ficaria sua dúvida com o código que você tem:

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(//string de conexao);


    int inicio = 22; //número do patrimonio inicial
    int quantidade = 10; //quantidade de números que serão inseridos

    string sqlInsert = @"INSERT INTO DadosNome (Nome, Valor, Teste, Deletar) Values ";

    for (int i = 0; i <= quantidade; i++)
    {
          sqlInsert += "('"+txtNome.Text+"', '"+ (inicio + i)  +"', '"+txtTeste.Text+"', '"+txtDeletar.Text+ "'),"; //vai concatenando a sintaxe dos values
    }

    sqlInsert = sqlInsert.Remove(sqlInsert.Lenght-1)+";"; //Remove a ultima virgula

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

Como já mencionei, não refiz o código alterando alguns problemas existentes. Recomendo a leitura sobre a utilização dos parâmetros ao utilizar um SqlCommand:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.macoratti.net/09/07/c_adn_7.htm

Além disso, é preciso tratar os erros que podem acontecer

Comment: @RonavannLinhalis, Também não tem impacto nesse cenário específico,  mas se não me falha a memória, existe um limite de 1000 `Values` para cada comando de `INSERT`

Comment: Muito obrigado @RovannLinhalis, consegui adaptar ao meu código deu certinho. Fazia dias que tentava e não dava certo...

Comment: @dionebravo não se esqueça de marcar como resposta. Obrigado